# Finding all elements in ng-content

Tags: angular

Given that `@ContentChildren('*')` does not seem to be supported [(at least for the time being)](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8563), I'm looking for alternate ways to basically get access to all of the components in my `ng-content`.
Basically I wish I could do something like:

```
@Component({selector: 'foo' template: `...`)}
class FooComponent {...}

@Component({selector: 'app' template: `<container><foo></foo></container>`)}
class AppComponent {...}

@Component({selector: 'container', template: `<ng-content>/ng-content>`})
export class Container {
    @ContentChildren('*') allComponents;   //wish I could get FooComponent here!
}
```

Workaround I came up with (and dismissed, in some cases) so far:
 1. <s>Have a base component and find using `@ContentChildren(Base)`</s>: I can't as some of these components aren't mine and I would like to avoid having to wrap around 3rd parties.
 2. <s>Query for native elements</s> I must have the component to interact with and set input.
 3. Mark the inner elements with a directive or #id - as a last resort, I could do that, but that's unfortunate that anyone who'd use my `ContainerComponent` would have to mark the content to be processed.

Any other way around it?..

Comment: a very good question, it probably can be generalized for `@ViewChildren` as well

Comment: @Maximus https://plnkr.co/edit/sKiyLG3NzwnxSWRO02sb?p=preview

Comment: @yurzui, thanks, that's very neat, although probably not applicable in production :). I think you should've used `15` here `x => x.flags & 1 << 15`, not `14` as shown [here](https://hackernoon.com/here-is-why-you-will-not-find-components-inside-angular-bdaf204d955c#7fa4). Or where you looking for directives as well? I didn't know I could find the `view`  on injector, but it's probably also not public API since everything should be queried from injector using `get(token)` and there's no token for the view. Right?

Comment: I think it's very dirty solution. Seems you're right: we should use `15` and this solution won't work with nested tags. we need to write more code for that :)

Comment: @yurzui, it's not dirty, it's undocumented :D

Comment: @Maximus First it is not public API. second it can be changed when `ngfactory` will be changed or even removed

Comment: @yurzui, yeah, I understand that) that's why I'm saying undocumented as in not publicly supported (uses private API)